# Delete database when on app update

Tags: android, sqlite

I have preloaded sqlite database located in assets, which is copied to default database location after app first installation. I'd like to do this procedure on each app update. 
I don't need to keep any user data from existing database.

How to delete old database file, when app is being updated?

Comment: manage app version in preference, if(appver < prefver ){check DB exist then delete}else{save new version or whatever}

Answer (score 3):

These are actually two questions:

- How do I do something on app update

You could save a variable with the last version code in a Shared Preferences. After each start of the application you check your current code with the saved code. If they don't match, it was an update and you execute some code.

- How do I delete a database

If the database is closed, you can simply delete the file. Use [Context.getDatabasePath(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) to find the location of the file, and [File.delete()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#delete()) for deleting it. Make sure no process is accessing the database file. If so, you might need to use the [File.deleteOnExit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()) and force a restart of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onUpgrade()` method of `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Delete old table 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);

    // Re-create table
    onCreate(db);
 }
```

Comment: OnUpgrade is called when database version is increaed. I'm not increasing version, I'm delivering new databse file in assets folder. Also, your statement is dropping table, not databse file.